# A word for an unintentional mistake

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I'm working on my summer reading, and one of the assignments I have to complete for a book is 'Latter of Advice.' My report was going great right before I got to the character's *unintentional mistake*. Now after every five to six words, the words (unintentional mistake) is written, and I really want to change that.

Comment: A mistake better be unintended or it's no mistake. Same with blunder or faux pas, even if you meant the words, your insult was unintentional.

Comment: The word is *mistake*--unmodified. For *unintentional* is wholly redundant as modifier for *mistake.*

Comment: An intentional mistake is the definition of "sabotage" :-)

Comment: "Latter of Advice"--really?  Teacher F.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like "writing advice".

Answer (score 2):

> A mistake better be unintended or it's no mistake. Same with blunder or faux pas, even if you meant the words, your insult was unintentional. - [@YosefBaskin](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/215927/yosef-baskin)
>
> The word is mistake--unmodified. For unintentional is wholly redundant as modifier for mistake. - [@CarlWitthoft](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/60044/carl-witthoft)

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not the same thing, I wonder if "unforced error" might not be more appropriate? An unforced error is from sports, originally tennis, I think.

Webster defines "unforced error"as:

> a missed shot or lost point (as in tennis) that is entirely a result of the player's own blunder and not because of the opponent's skill or effort

I'm not sure this qualifies as an answer, but reading the comments to the question, I think it is clear that the question is probably not valid.